# How to check if a line segment intersects a simple polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the visibility graph algorithm from the Computational Geometry book by De Berg, et al. You can find the algorithm here: http://cs.smith.edu/~streinu/Teaching/Courses/274/Spring98/Projects/Philip/fp/algVisibility.htm

I'm having trouble with the first line of the VISIBLE algorithm:

```
if pwi intersects the interior of the obstacle of which wi is a vertex, locally at wi then return false
```

The book states that it should take O(lg n) time (where n is all the points in the plane), but it doesn't explain how to do the check. The algorithms I have found take linear time in relation to the number of vertices of the polygon.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: He/she wants to know how to do it in O(log n) time. But I think that's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the step with which you are concerned takes at most O(log *n*) time,
because you can use binary search on the obstacle for which *w*<sub>i</sub> is a vertex.

Comment: Do you mean doing a binary search in the w array? Looking for what? I don't see it.

Comment: I think I got it. Assuming _p_ is a vertex of the polygon and _q_ and _r_ are their adjacent vertices in the polygon then for all the vertices _v_ between _q_ and _r_ in the _w_ array the segment _pv_ will be inside the polygon. And all the other vertices not visible in the polygon will have a line segment blocking them. Is that correct?

Comment: I just tested it and it seems to work. Thanks! Love your work btw.

Comment: @user5701449: Thanks! :-)